# How to make gtest print its output to the console?

Tags: c++, docker, centos, googletest, autotools

I'm porting an autotools project from CentOS 6 without docker to a CentOS 8 docker. When I run `make check`, instead of printing everything to the console like it used to, it is printing only:

```
PASS: unit_tests_for_component_x
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for my-product 0.10
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

In case of a failed test, it prints:

```
FAIL: unit_tests_component_x
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for my-product 0.10
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See component_x/test-suite.log
Please report to support@mycompany.com
============================================================================
```

And then I have to open the `component_x/test-suite.log` file in order to see what happend.

Note: this also happens on CentOS 8 without docker.

I would much prefer to have gtest just print it all on the console, both the PASSED tests and the FAILED tests, even if it's overly verbose - I'm comfortable with that.

Environment details:
`gtest-1.7.0-0`, official `CentOS 8.1.1911` docker, `autotools 2.69`, `gcc 8.3.1`

Many thanks

Comment: GTest prints to console by default, so it's your test runner that captures (or forces GTest to redirect) output. You can check [the docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/release-1.8.0/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#running-test-programs-advanced-options) and try to get the output back, but I'm not sure if it will help (e.g. if your GTest is setup to print to output and test runner pipes that into file, you can't do anything but change the test runner).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thanks. I'm considering to just dump the log file to the console. Now I'm looking for a way to do that. I want to dump just the log file with the failed test.